# boost simple human readable date time of now

Tags: c++, boost

Anyone know how to get a simple date format from boost of the current time to a local system?

```
boost::posix_time::ptime now = boost::posix_time::second_clock::universal_time();
boost::posix_time::time_facet *facet = new boost::posix_time::time_facet("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S");
```

I've seen examples that say to use cout.imbue but I just want a simple string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try this code:

```
void FormatDateTime(
    std::string const&              format,
    boost::posix_time::ptime const& date_time,
    std::string&                    result)
  {
    boost::posix_time::time_facet * facet =
      new boost::posix_time::time_facet(format.c_str());
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream.imbue(std::locale(stream.getloc(), facet));
    stream << date_time;
    result = stream.str();
  }
```

Set format to `"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"` or whatever facet you want.

For the local time, use `boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time()` as the second argument (`date_time`).

Comment: This isn't specific to the local computer ... i need boost::posix_time::ptime now = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();

Comment: doesn't creating a new facet and imbueing it every time this function is called cause a lot of overhead?

Comment: As far as performance is concerned, if you are always using the same format, you can probably use the same stream for every formatting operation, and then you won't have to imbue the facet every time. Nevertheless I have never tried. Also I don't know what is the overhead of creating the facet and imbuing it.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's too late but for searchers like me:

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>

const boost::posix_time::ptime now = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();

const boost::wformat f = boost::wformat(L"%02d.%02d.%s  %02d:%02d")
                % now.date().year_month_day().dayas_number()
                % now.date().year_month_day().month.as_number()
                % now.date().year_month_day().year
                % now.time_of_day().hours()
                % now.time_of_day().minutes();

const std::wstring result = f.str();  // "21.06.2013  14:38"
```

Comment: it should be day.as_number(). can't edit because of the 6-character limit.

Comment: I tested the code and year is not always formatted correctly. Sometimes the year contains a comma (2,017.01.11-16:18:01), sometimes not (2017.01.11-16:18:01), tested on Mac OS. This std::to_wstring(now.date().year_month_day().year) helped.